# Stop Cisco VPN AnyConnect from detecting logoff under linux

Tags: login, vpn

Cisco VPN AnyConnect automatically detects when the user that initiated the VPN session logs off and then also disconnects the VPN connection.
I want to prevent this from happening.
I tried to use a screen session which is persistent after logoff but the VPN still got disconnected.

The questions are:

- what could be the possible mechanisms that the vpn client uses to detect the logout
- how could I stop the VPN client from disconnecting (I am not able to modify the Cisco connection profile XML)

I do have root access to the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After analyzing the behavior of the vpn client a bit deeper, I found out that it doesn't look for the process or its parent processes but simply keeps track of all login sessions at the time the VPN connection is made.

This means, if you have 2 login sessions A and B open while you connect the VPN and you close any of the two, the VPN will disconnect.

My solution is to remove the session from utmp (utmp is basically what shows up if you run `w` or `who`), prior to connecting with the client.
For that purpose, I wrote a little tool called `utmpremove`, with its source code listed below:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct utmp *u; // Used to read existing entries
    struct utmp newent; // Used for new entry (to delete)

    char *my_tty = ttyname(STDIN_FILENO);
    
    printf("Searching utmp for my TTY: %s\n", my_tty);

    setutent();
    
    int found_myself = 0;

    for (;;) {
        u = getutent();

        if(!u) break;
        if(u->ut_type != USER_PROCESS) continue;

        // Get TTY of this utmp entry (taken from source of 'w')
        char tty[5 + UT_LINESIZE + 1] = "/dev/";
        for (int i = 0; i < UT_LINESIZE; i++) {
            /* clean up tty if garbled */
            if (isalnum(u->ut_line[i]) || (u->ut_line[i] == '/'))
                tty[i + 5] = u->ut_line[i];
            else
                tty[i + 5] = '\0';
        }

        // Check if this matches ours
        printf("- utmp tty: %s\n", tty);
        if(strcmp(my_tty, tty) == 0) {
            printf("This is me! Removing...\n");
            found_myself = 1;
            memcpy(newent.ut_id, u->ut_id, sizeof(u->ut_id));
            break;
        }
    }

    // Remove entry if found
    if(found_myself) {
        newent.ut_type = DEAD_PROCESS;
        memset(newent.ut_line, 0, UT_LINESIZE);
        newent.ut_time = 0;
        memset(newent.ut_user, 0, UT_NAMESIZE);

        setutent();
        if(pututline(&newent)) {
            printf("Removed utmp entry successfully.\n");
            endutent();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            printf("Failed removing utmp entry.\n");
            endutent();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        printf("No matching utmp entry found.\n");
        endutent();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}
```

The command line would then look something like this:

```sh
(sudo ./utmpremove) && /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect
```